# Why the if-condition is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
if (options.renderLinkUpload) {
  if($(element).find(".uploadcss").length == 0) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

I can see the `// Do something` part is executed even if

```
$(element).find(".uploadcss").length == 0
```

is `false`

Any inputs?

Comment: Hope you missed if(!$(element).find(".uploadcss").length == 0) not operator

Comment: With jQuery you must use size() method: $(element).find(".uploadcss").size() > 0

Comment: But the problem is here it that , even the length ==0, and Length > 0, the //Do nothing is getting executed.

Comment: Post some html for a more effective question

Comment: This is html 
            <div class="row-fluid indexable">
                <div class="fileUploadSection"></div>
                <div class="linkUploadTemplate" data-bind="template: { name: 'link-upload-template' }"></div>
       
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 if(!$(element).find(".uploadcss").length == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `==`, the boolean `false` and int `0` are the same, so `(false == 0)` evaluates to `true`.

To avoid this, use `===`:

```
false == 0; // true
false === 0; // false
```